# Poor execution plan within insert trigger for UPDATE to base table having primary key on identity column as the number of inserted rows varies

Tags: sql-server, performance, triggers

I have a table `t1` with a primary key on the identity column of this table. Within the insert trigger of `t1`, an UPDATE statement is being issued to update some columns of the newly inserted rows, the join being on `t1.primarykeycolumn` and `inserted.primarykeycolumn`.

When the number of inserted rows starts to creep up, I have noticed 'suboptimal' execution plans. I guess the optimizer is referring to the statistics on t1 to arrive at the execution plan. But for newly inserted rows, the statistics page is always going to be stale, after all the IDENTITY columns is always going to be monotonically increasing when the SQL Server is supplying the values.

To prove that statistics are the 'issue', I issued an `UPDATE STATISTICS` command as the first statement in the trigger and the optimizer is able to come up with a very good plan for a wide variety of rows. But I certainly cannot issue `UPDATE STATISTICS` in production code for a mostly OLTP system.

Most of the times, the number of rows inserted will be in the few tens and only occasionally in the couple of thousands. When the number of rows in the tens, the execution plan shows only nested loop joins while it switches to using a series of Merge Joins + Stream Aggregates at some point as the number of rows starts to creep up.

I want to avoid writing convoluted code within the trigger, one part for handling large number of rows and the other for the smaller number of rows. After all, this is what the server is best at doing. Is there a way to tell the optimizer 'even though you do not see the inserted values in the statistics, the distribution is going to be exactly like those that have been inserted before. please come up with the plan based on this assumption'? Any pointers appreciated.

After experimenting a bit, I have the following observation :
In the absence of a statistics, the optimizer is coming up with optimal plans for a very wide number of rows. It is only when the statistics are updated before issuing the inserts (i.e when there are statistics are available), the optimizer  comes up with 'bad' plans on the join between inserted & base table inside the trigger as the number of rows starts to go up.

Is there a way to tell the optimizer 'ignore whatever is on the statistics page, go do whatever you were doing in the absence of statistics"?

Comment: To the guy who instinctively votes down, at a minimum provide an explanation why you voted it down.

Comment: I assume that person did that because of the wall of text, and the lack of any code: the trigger(s) code, table definition(s) and any indices defined on the table(s) involved, plus the execution plan. It is hard to guess in the wild without seeing some concrete code. In any case I offsetted the loss  for you.

Comment: One thing you can try, and I'm speculating here as I don't see any of your trigger's code: Add `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` at the end your trigger statement(s) showing the performance problem. This will not use the cached execution plan which might use incorrect cardinalities in the tables involved.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, INSTEAD OF INSERT triggers are a viable option. See http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1826794-3387-1.aspx